# mongodb with 13.10 service problems

Tags: 13.10, services, mongodb

I installed mongodb with the instructions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). Fresh installation of ubuntu btw. It installed without error, but upon attempting to start, stop or restart the service, I got

```
start: Unknown job: mongodb
```

Invoking "mongod" from the commandline seems to work, as I can view statistics of mongodb fine from localhost:28017.

I've also attempted to use the official ubuntu package "mongodb" instead of "mongodb-10gen" but no luck there either.

Comment: Try with downloading particular .deb file of mongodb-10gen from Debian install list and installing it with `sudo dpkg -i <file name>`

Comment: Same error. This is the exact link I used http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/10gen/binary-i386/mongodb-10gen_2.4.8_i386.deb

Comment: If so, then uninstall it. Install `mongodb` in Ubuntu repository. Then try with reinstall with that 'mongodb-10gen' .deb file upon Ubuntu repository one. That may be replaced. But see...

Comment: Just to note, I tried to reproduce this but cannot - service commands work just fine for me with the 10gen package and ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

Upstart has changed in 13.10 allowing user sessions. So this means that you must execute  service like this (even from root account):

```
sudo service mongodb restart
```

See this page:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181441